# Wix - install a component if at least one of the features is installed

Tags: wix, installation

In a Wix installer, I have many features, and a component for the documentation. I use a feature tree, so the user can select what features to install. I want the component for the documentation to be installed if at least one of the features is selected.

If no feature is selected, then I don't want the component to be installed (in that case, the product shouldn't install at all).

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the component to each of the features. You might find it convenient to use a [ComponentRef](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/componentref.html) or [CompononentGroupRef](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/componentgroupref.html).